# Delphi AddObject -not adding object

Tags: string, delphi

I am stumped by this strange problem. I pass a Memo.Lines as TStrings to a procedure and fill it with AddObject. But the object is not getting added (checked immediately by a `L := TURLLinkObject(AStrings.Objects [AStrings.Count -1])`.  (Edit: AddObject returns 0 which is the index of the added item as per Delphi's [Help](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate3/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TStrings_AddObject.html))

Here is my procedure:

```
type
  TURLLinkObject = class(TObject)
    url,
    attr,
    name : string;
  end;

procedure getLinks(XMLNode: TNode; AStrings: TStrings; Match:string='');

var L : TURLLinkObject;
    i : integer;
    S : string;

begin;
  if XMLNode = nil then exit;

  if (XmlNode.NodeName = 'a') and (XmlNode As TElement).hasAttribute('href') then
  begin;
    L := TURLLinkObject.Create;
    L.url := (XmlNode AS TElement).getAttribute('href');
    L.attr := GetAttributesText(XmlNode);
    L.Name := 'Some Name';

    if (Match = '') or (pos(Match, L.url) <> 0) then
    begin;
       s := format('%s :: %s', [L.Name, L.url]);
       i := AStrings.AddObject(s, L);
       L := TURLLinkObject(AStrings.Objects[AStrings.Count -1]);
    end
    else
      L.Free;
  end;

  if XMLNode.hasChildNodes then
  begin
    for i:= 0 to XMLNode.childNodes.length-1  do
      getLinks(XMLNode.ChildNodes.item(i), AStrings, PartialMatchName);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The 2nd sentence in the help you linked under Description states what the return value is.

Comment: @Jason, yes, I just posted an edit before seeing your comment. My oversight, but that doesn't help with the nil object

Comment: What do you mean when you checked immediately?  is L nil after the call to L := TURLLinkObject(AStrings.Objects[AStrings.Count -1]);? I don't see how that could be.  You could use i instead of AStrings.Count-1 but shouldn't make much of a difference.  If your memo is not being populated show us how you are populating that as I don't see anything immediately wrong with what you have here

Comment: It is weird to see semicolons after `begin` (though it is syntactically valid - Pascal compiler considers excessive semicolons as empty statements and ignores).

Comment: I guess the lesson here is that you should not use GUI controls as your primary data store. Use GUI controls simply for display purposes. Hold the data in a structure that is designed for the task.

Comment: Adding to @David: It is OK to associate, say, a listbox item with a certain object, but the association should not be used as storage.

Comment: @David: I use this as a quick way to transfer two strings (name, url) in a structured way across two units. Very temporary. The objects are freed once used in the calling unit.   The lesson I learned here is that you just don't trust (your objects) to the Delphi compiler. Is it too much to expect an error message when callng AddObject on Memo.Lines. How can Delphi simply swallow the object ?

Comment: You reap what you sow. TMemo is an appallingly choice for this!

Comment: @ss2006: Do I get that right? You abuse a TMemo to pass two strings between two units? Why not simply pass the two strings directly, or put them in a record? Using a TComponent for that is not the right choice. Oh, and the online help tells you: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Classes.TStrings.Objects "Setting the Objects property for TStrings has no effect. Reading the Objects property for TStrings returns nil (Delphi) or NULL (C++). Descendant classes can associate objects with the strings in the set by implementing the Objects property."

Comment: @Rudy I am returning a list of all urls on a webpage with its name, link and attributes.  (potentially dozens to hundreds of links, and each link has two -or three, if attr is present- string type data  associated with it). So, the Memo is bringing back several records and each record has two strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TMemo.Lines` type is derived from `TStrings` and does not support `Objects` property; `Objects` support is implemented in `TStringList` type, so you can't use `Objects` with `TMemo.Lines`.

Comment: Thanks user 246408. This is the problem.  Isn't it strange for Delphi ("a structured programming language", Hmmm..) to accept such code.   Both `Object` property and `AddObject` method are accepted by the compiler and at run time without raising any errors.  The added object simply vanishes.

Comment: @ss2006 `TStrings` type simply ignores object references, ex passed as `AddObjects` arguments; and if you access `Objects` property you get `nil` because `TStrings` instance does contain objects.
I agree that VCL could implement corresponding `TStrings` or `TMemoStrings` methods so that they raise exception instead of just doing nothing but the problem you encountered is a rare one and probably VCL designers decided it does not deserve attention.